# Need help selecting certain element with jquery in PHP while loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php while loop that is looping through results, and outputting them into an UL as LI items.

Each new li item has a section with an "open details" button. I'm having trouble getting this "Open details" button to open the hidden panel (which I'm also hiding with jquery).

I can get the panel to work just fine with 1 result, but as I have multiple results, I can get each "open details" button to just open that li item's hidden container.

I am auto incrementing results as each new loop comes in. That way it's doing this "panelopen1" "panelopen2" and so forth with each button in each new li item.

Then I'm just trying to use jQuery to use these newly created li items with their incremented "panelopen" buttons to just select the next element with id="panel" to be able to toggle it show/hide. Panel is hidden by default

```
   $( "li[id^='panel']" ).hide();  

    $( "p[id^='panelopen']" ).on('click', function (event){
                $( "li[id^='panel']" ).toggle();
    });


     <li class="row bars">                                                
      <div class="col-sm-1 btn btn-secondary">
        <p id="panelopen$i">details</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="panel" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <textarea type="text" name="description">'; echo 
   $row['description']; echo'</textarea>
      </div>
    </li> ';
```

Can't get the open button to just open that panel for that li item, instead all item panels are opening.

Comment: Use classes instead of ID's.  And this sample code isn't enough for us to see what the issue is.... please see how to create an [mcve], and create a _runnable snippet_ so we can see the issue happen.

Comment: i'm sorry but your question is really not clear. but as i understood part of your question i believe you need something like Ajax to create real time text